# Combine ActionCable and I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, actioncable

I've started using Rails ActionCable to deliver messages to my users without them needing to reload the page. My websites are all translated in multiple languages and I'm having trouble finding a solution to the following problem:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast 'user_last_seen_at_refresh', {
  user_partial: Admin::UsersController.render(partial:"user", locals: { u:u }),
  user_id:u.id
}
```

When I'm broadcasting a message to some of my users, they need to see a partial that is translated. This is not. The partial is translated to English, which is the default locale. A 'solution' I can think of is doing the following:

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |l|
  I18n.with_locale(l) do
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "user_last_seen_at_refresh_#{l}", {
      user_partial: Admin::UsersController.render(partial:"user", locals: { u:u }),
      user_id:u.id
    }
  end
end
```

and subscribing my users according to their language, but that just doesn't feel like the Rails way to go.

Has anybody got a better idea than this?
Thx!

Comment: Great question, I had the exact same problem in mind and was wondering if this approach was considered good practice.

Comment: Three years later, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Jake I’ve implemented the second piece of code I posted and am still using it today. The users are subscribed to the channelnames with their locale, so only see their language. Never had any issues with it actually.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |l|
  I18n.with_locale(l) do
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "user_last_seen_at_refresh_#{l}", {
      user_partial: Admin::UsersController.render(partial:"user", locals: { u:u }),
      user_id:u.id
    }
  end
end
```

You are actually making the same broadcast call for the user in ALL of the available locales.

What i think you want is to send the broadcast to users in their favourite locale. Right? To do so, (*assuming* you have some field/method to access the locale of a user), change it as below:

```
I18n.with_locale(u.locale) do
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "user_last_seen_at_refresh", {
    user_partial: Admin::UsersController.render(partial:"user", locals: { u:u }),
    user_id:u.id
  }
end
```

Comment: Well that's the problem, if I do this, all users seeing this partial will see it in 1 language...